# How to convert hex to binary in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to get some help with my assignment. I have to convert hex to binary by using `hlookup` or conditional formatting in Excel.

How should I approach this?

Comment: What you are asking is confusing... If you just asked for converting HEX to BIN, I'd tell you to use the built-in functions in excel to do that but I can't see where hlookup or conditional formatting comes in. hlookup might be to match characters for the conversion (which I can't see) but conditional formatting!? I'm not aware that conditional formatting changes the values of a cell.

Comment: Same here, the built-in functions do what you're asking but have nothing to do with hlookup.http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hex2bin-function-HP010342567.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From the Excel Help article [Convert numbers to different number systems](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Convert-numbers-to-different-number-systems-880EEB52-6E90-4A9D-9E56-ACABA6A27560) (specifically, the section **Convert a hexadecimal number to binary**):

> To do this task, use the `HEX2BIN` function.
>
> ```
> =HEX2BIN("F", 8)          Converts hexadecimal F to binary, with 8 characters (00001111)
> =HEX2BIN("B7")            Converts hexadecimal B7 to binary (10110111)
> =HEX2BIN("FFFFFFFFFF")    Converts hexadecimal FFFFFFFFFF to binary (1111111111)
> ```

Comment: The link above is dead. Here's an updated link: [Convert numbers to different number systems](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Convert-numbers-to-different-number-systems-880EEB52-6E90-4A9D-9E56-ACABA6A27560)

Comment: @user2070305 Thanks :) Feel free to edit the answer the next time you find a mistake

Comment: The last one really does only return 1111111111 (10 binary digits). But why? Is there a limit of 10 for the output (and the input as well?)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Excel's HEX2BIN function.  It can be found [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hex2bin-function-HP010342567.aspx).  Excel is a very powerful tool that can do many other things for you.

Comment: My teacher ask us to use conditional formatting or hlookup only. Yes I want to convert HEX to BIN. thank you

Comment: @dalia67: Did your teacher also say anything about asking people on the internet for the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a complete answer because I gather you are supposed to be learning rather than just copying, but if you know what the possible hex values are (ie not just 0-9) and you know how to represent these in binary (ie `\x2` is equivalent to `bin 10`) then since you have a one-to-one relationship you could create a table of equivalents and use that to 'covert' one version to the other.